# cakePHP - Filter results before contain

Tags: cakephp-1.3, contains

I have a `Contract` model, that `hasMany` records of `Debt` model.

I'm using contain to get those debt records. but i need to filter out any record with no debts.
To do so, i need to add a sub-query or join.

Is there another way?
And
Which is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you exclude debts from the Contracts, with CakePHP you should use Join options:

```
$options['joins'] = array(
array('table' => 'debts',
    'alias' => 'Debt',
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'conditions' => array(
        'debt.id = Contract.debt_id',
        'debt.value IS NULL'
    )
)
); 

$contracts = $Contract->find('all', $options);
```

or maybe try
 `$this->Contract->find('all', array( 
    'contain' => array("Debt.value" => null)
));`